# WSO2 Message Broker message counter error and WAS integration

Tags: wso2

I'm trying to use the WSO2 Message Broker solution but i have some problems/questions that i hope someone can help me.

We detect a problem on a Queue message counter, that counts 100 messages but after we open it don't show up any message. This problem occurs when the Message Broker end's abruptly, and we don't know if it's only a problem with the counter or if is a message lost problem.

Other question is if it's possible to run this solution on a Websphere Application Server?

Here is the logs and image from Message Broker console [logs](https://mega.co.nz/#!a45CwSZB!mT5KHtBVCZBfiSjwPOaPN-pLmTuwM0e9lszrAhZTJTw) and   [Console](https://mega.co.nz/#!HloggBjI!61Q3DZJVtQk6d0mu-tqIVckgh7m3MAjWs3FScbKjYig) files

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you share some logs or code to narrow down the issue you're having? At the moment this is very broad. Also, asking for links to documentation is not appropriate for an SO question.

Comment: [logs](https://mega.co.nz/#!a45CwSZB!mT5KHtBVCZBfiSjwPOaPN-pLmTuwM0e9lszrAhZTJTw) and [Console](https://mega.co.nz/#!HloggBjI!61Q3DZJVtQk6d0mu-tqIVckgh7m3MAjWs3FScbKjYig)

Comment: Er, I mean something more specific you can identify in the logs, not the whole log for us to sift through - that's up to you to do. I don't think anybody is just going to download a random zipfile from an unknown source.